# javascript function with variable needed to trigger a url with value from within script

Tags: javascript

i have an html page with some inputs, i need to trigger a js function that will ultimately lead to triggering a url GET or POST (with out credentials) the problem is i need to see this in my url

`http://restaubid.com/cgi-bin/mmcal.cgi?restaubid/keyword/oven`

instead I see this

`http://localhost:8080/?keyword=oven&email=`

Don't worry about the email; I am using a thymleaf for front end and java for back end database to save email.

For now i really need to trigger the url with the right url which is this

`http://restaubid.com/cgi-bin/mmcal.cgi?restaubid/keyword/oven`

[image]

my code is as follows (index.html)

```html
<div class="col span-2-of-2">
            <form action="">
                <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" placeholder="Search">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email (Optional)">
                <button type="submit" onclick="equipmentSearchFn()">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

for script i have within my html file (index.html)

```html
<script>
function equipmentSearchFn() {
    let keyword;
    let email;
    let url;

    keyword = document.getElementById("keyword").value;
    email = document.getElementById("email").value

    document.getElementById("keyword").innerHtml = keyword;
    document.getElementById("email").innerHtml = email;


    let xmlHttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for modern browsers
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {

        }
    }
    url = "http://restaubid.com/cgi-bin/mmcal.cgi?restaubid/keyword/" + keyword;
    //window.location = url + keyword;
    xmlHttp.open('GET', url, true);
    xmlHttp.send();

}
</script>
```

i am much obliged...

Comment: I rolled back the edit that was done to this question, as it actually broke the question by turning illustrative links into clickable links with their url's hidden. I re-edited as well, to properly format everything.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here. The first it the "submit" button. Unless you stop the click event with javascript, the button will POST the values to your Form.

The second problem is the AJAX request, which I think you don't need at all.

```js
function equipmentSearchFn() {
    let keyword;
    let email;
    let url;

    keyword = document.getElementById("keyword").value;
    email = document.getElementById("email").value

    url = "http://restaubid.com/cgi-bin/mmcal.cgi?restaubid/keyword/" + keyword;
    window.location = url + keyword;

}
```

```html
<div class="col span-2-of-2">
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" placeholder="Search">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email (Optional)">
        <button type="button" onclick="equipmentSearchFn()">Search</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: i took off the <form action=""> also the url has + keyword i removed that so as to keep it like this  url = "http://restaubid.com/cgi-bin/mmcal.cgi?restaubid/keyword/"  the keyword is already added in the window.locaiton ..  i then ran the code but its not working .. i don't know if window.location is a post and needs some server credentials but its not working ... the page i says This feature is not available in the restaubid workgroup.. which is odd because if you run restaubid.com/cgi-bin/mncal.cgi?restaubid/keyword/oven i do get a query result set from the databse